# ¿Asignar api publica de Marvel a un dominio de Github?

Tags: javascript, api, github, fetch

acabo de terminar un proyecto consumiendo una api publica pero cuando la subo a github no hay forma y marvel en este caso bloquea los datos.
Aun agregando el dominio en la web no puedo acceder a los datos que haciendo pruebas con el localhost podia.

el dominio es: https://fedenu1993.github.io/marvel/

Como dice ahi debo quitar el http y el * vendria a ser un comodin para los subdominios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `fenedu1993.` ya es un subdominio, intenta quitando `*.`

Comment: Ya probe de varias formas.. Sera que tardan en autorizarlo? :(

Comment: Abre la página, revisa la consola y verás que se bloqueó el acceso a `http://gateway.marvel.com` porque el origen es seguro y el destino no. Intenta cambiar a `https://gateway.marvel.com`